# zabbix graphs only work with 6h time frame?

Tags: grafana, zabbix, agent

Ive just added two zabbix agents to my zabbix server. One agent on windows, and another on linux. For both of them, I can see data coming into zabbix via latest data, but if I want to view the graphs, in the "to box" (timeframe box) I must enter "now/d" otherwise, nothing shows up at all. And the moment I do that, the timeframe shifts from whatever I set it to (1h , 2h, 5m, etc) to 6 hours. And if i change it, the data disappears again. Is there a setting i need to set? This is a new zabbix instance and everything is still default on the server. I also have grafana pulling from zabbix, and for any graphs in grafana that use zabbix data, I have to do the now/d thing as well. I included two pictures, the first is showing the only graph I can get (with now/d) and the other showing when I choose the most recent graph, showing there is no data is I do not do the now/d thing.

[zabbix working, now/d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xKc9.png)
[zabbix not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q57tu.png)

Comment: Check date/timezone on all your servers. If agent sends data with different date than on zabbix server then such things can happen. Most ridiculous is when agent sends data from the future :) And yes... zabbix for some reason sets time of received data not from system time but from agent time.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The two graphs you posted show the same data: nothing from 14:26 to 15:26 in both of them.